# php get_headers result displaying

Tags: php, http, header

I was used to get_headers() function

```
`$`url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$s=get_headers(`$`url, 1);
print_r(`$`s);
```

**then i got output like**

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Cache-Control] => public, max-age=27 [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 [Expires] => Mon, 07 Nov 2011 13:44:38 GMT [Last-Modified] => Mon, 07 Nov 2011 13:43:38 GMT [Vary] => * [Date] => Mon, 07 Nov 2011 13:44:10 GMT [Connection] => close [Content-Length] => 195251 )
```

**How can display like**

Cache-Control :

Content-Type  :

Expires       :

Last-Modified :

Connection    :

Content-Length :

Comment: So you're getting the array, and you're asking how to display the value of that array?  Seems like something that should be looked into for 30 seconds prior to asking here.  Link to get you started:  [http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php)

Comment: `get_headers` Inconsistency : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781795/get-headers-inconsistency

Answer (score 3):

`get_headers()` returns an array. If you set the second optional paramater to `1` then it will return an array with intuitive keys.

E.g. `getheaders($url, 1)`

You can print them seperately like so:

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$s = get_headers($url, 1);

print("Cache-Control: ".$s[Cache-Control]."\n");
print("Content-Type: ".$s[Content-Type]."\n");
print("Expires: ".$s[Expires]."\n");
print("Last-Modified: ".$s[Last-Modified]."\n");
```

For a full definition see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).

Answer (score 0):

Of just use

```
print_r(), var_dump() or var_export()
```

to display result